# CSS absolute position where top left of div is at the top right of the parent

Tags: html, css

I want to absolute position a div such that the top left corner of the div is attached to top right corner of the parent div (relative positioned).

Do you have any solutions how to do that ?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/ZeSF8/) to start

Comment: Post your code and/or start a jsfiddle.

Comment: Compatibility for? If you want to let it work in < IE8 i recommend javascript. Else use the HTML5 calculations.

Comment: ok. let me put a fiddle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you want something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/kdcmq/

```
<div id = "parent">
     <div id = "child"></div>
</div>


#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    display: block; /* fix for opera and ff */
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%; /* this line of code will sort things out for you :) */
}
```

Comment: If the parent is not `<div>` (span or outher inline element) - don't forget to add `display: block` for Opera (Presto) and FF.

Comment: can you explain why parent position should be relative  ??

Answer (score 3):

Simple as this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZeSF8/2/

CSS:

```
div {border:1px solid #000}
.p {
    position:relative;
    width:100px; /*width will be unknown*/
    height:80px;
    background:#999;
}

.c {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}
```

​
HTML:

```
<div class="p">
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>​
```